# preg_replace between something without removing the something

Tags: php, preg-replace, symbols, apostrophe

What i'm gonna do is:

```
function replace_between_something($betweenWhat,$replace_thing,$target){
return preg_replace("/".$betweenWhat."(.*?)".$betweenWhat."/",$replace_thing,$target);
}
$string="Hi, *my* name is 'Soul' and she is 'Maggie'. ";

$replace=replace_between_something("\*","your",$string);
$replace=replace_between_something("'","noname",$replace);

echo $replace;
```

the output expected is:

```
Hi, *your* name is 'noname' and she is 'noname'.
```

but, the real output (which is not as expected):

```
Hi, your name is noname and she is noname.
```

How to keep the symbol ??

anybody can help me???

sorry, i just edit my question to show the actual things i wanna do.

Comment: Just put the quotes into your substitution, like `$replace=preg_replace("/'(.*?)'/","'noname'",$string);` .

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want that way..

Comment: can we tell the regex to select only the inside quote ? (only select content instead of 'content' )

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien `return preg_replace("/".$betweenWhat."(.*?)".$betweenWhat."/",$betweenWhat . $replace_thing . $betweenWhat,$target);` + Use `preg_quote()` to escape `$betweenWhat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use `preg_quote` for escaping characters like as

```
function replace_between_something($betweenWhat, $replace_thing, $target) {
    return preg_replace("/" . preg_quote($betweenWhat) . "(.*?)" . preg_quote($betweenWhat) . "/", $betweenWhat.$replace_thing.$betweenWhat, $target);
}

$string = "Hi, *my* name is 'Soul' and she is 'Maggie'. ";

$replace = replace_between_something("*", "your", $string) . "\n";
$replace = replace_between_something("'", "noname", $replace);

echo $replace;
```

The special regular expression characters are: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`

> **delimiter**
> If the optional delimiter is specified, it will also be escaped. This is useful for escaping the delimiter that is required by the PCRE functions. The `/` is the most commonly used delimiter.

So you don't need to `--->` `\*` that backslash for escaping as `preg_quote` in itself escape those characters

[**Docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/7KHYL)

Comment: Specifying the delimiter for `preg_quote()` will help in case OP uses `/` as $betweenWhat

Answer (score 3):

You could just include the quotes again in the replacement string:

```
$string="Hi, my name is 'Soul' and she is 'Maggie'. ";
$replace=preg_replace("/'(.*?)'/","'noname'",$string);
echo $replace;
```